# Wrapping a div with Noscript tag programatically

Tags: jquery, noscript

I have a div inside noscript tags

```
 <noscript>
        <div id="googleImg" style="display:inline;">
        </div>
 </noscript>
```

In a ajax call success I remove the noscript tags, add an element inside the div.  This is how I add the element inside;

```
var a = $jq("noscript").text();
            $jq("noscript").remove();
            $jq("body").append(a);


            $jq("#googleImg").append(adwordsImg);
```

but I failed to put the noscript tags back around. How can I do it? I tried jquery.wrap but couldn't get it done.

PS: Reason for this is; I'm trying to implement Adwords to a website and because of caching mechanism, I can't just add the code into html and forget. I need to make some dynamic changes on some parameters. That's why I remove the noscript first and then try to put it back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.html()` will only get the content of the element. You can add the no script element around it by creating a new noscript element.

```
        var a = $jq("noscript").text();
        $jq("noscript").remove();
        var noscript = document.createElement("noscript");
        $jq(noscript).append(a);
        $jq("body").append(noscript);
        $jq("#googleImg").append(adwordsImg);
```